# Unity editor frame drops on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use Unity in a Mac but the editor drops frames all the time. It shows it's rendering 330 fps but still feels laggy and dropping frames, also enemy movement is weird (I think it´s because it's dropping frames). This doesn't happen on windows (I tried both platforms). Before I used metal, and it rendered 35 - 45 fps dropping frames too. When I switched to OpenGL it went up to 330fps. I think the problem is not performance, but incompatibility of some kind. When I play the game built for Mac it works well.

Any idea of what could it be?

Statistics using OpenGL:

[image: Statistics using OpenGL]

Statistics using Metal:

[image]

Comment: As of Unity 2021.1.71, macOS Big Sur 11.3 on a high end iMac Pro with Radeon Pro Vega 64X 16 GB, at date 25 of May, 2021 I still can experiment exactly the same issue I'd be extremely  curious what could cause this issue 
Switching to OpenGL usage forcibly in Unity Player settings shows more than twice as bigger FPS in the editor than using Metal!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure metal is enabled in the editor (not just when you export the game).
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Metal.html

in old unity version metal was not enabled by default on mac and you had to use `-force-gfx-metal` and start the editor with terminal command line.

If it still not working I'm not sure what you can try... maybe try also to change your screen res.
Remember that Unity editor always use more resource, if the game is working fine when you export the game you can ignore the problem.